# How can I make a copy of an installed Report?

Tags: ssrs

I have a working installation of SQL Server Reporting Services (2008) in which I've setup a DEV directory and successfully upload a number of report templates. I have now created a TEST directory. How can I copy the report templates from DEV to TEST?

Answer (score 1):

I just just downloaded [RSScripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) for a similar situation and it worked fine. Be sure to read the read me file as it's operation is not readily apparent.